# laravel npm run dev give error "webpack not installed"

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

i want use laravel mix with npm run dev but
this return error:

```
webpack not installed

Install webpack to start bundling:
$ npm install --save-dev webpack

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\taher\Desktop\kalashomar
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\taher\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-02T08_34_28_436Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\taher\Desktop\kalashomar
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "npm run development"
```

i tried this commands:

```
 npm install --save-dev webpack
 yarn add webpack --save-dev

 npm cache clean --force
 npm install
 npm install cross-env --save-dev
```

i also removed package-lock.json and yarn.lock and renistall but still return this error
please help

Answer (score 1):

first of fall download node.js ( https://nodejs.org/en/ ) or update in your device.
after successfully installed, try this..

npm install ,
npm run dev

Comment: node js is installed on my device version 15 and also tried npm install several time

Comment: try to globally install .. update node(1. npm install -g node ) ,2. npm install --global cross-env  , 3. npm install autoprefixer@9.8.0     / after that try to run may that's will be run in there..

Comment: there have the version problem in there. that's why npm not able to install...